# Generic gamepad support monogame

Tags: monogame

I recently made the transition from xna to monogame, but I am now stuck in a pretty big problem. I do not have an xbox 360 controller, so i have been using x360ce and dropping the .dll into the xna debug folder, and my gamepad would work fine. However, the same does not work with monogame. Is there a way in which I can use a non-xbox controller with monogame?

Comment: I have never heard of x360ce but at a guess I'd say you'll need to recompile it against the MonoGame dlls.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://monogame.codeplex.com/discussions/428651

Comment: Hi guys, I think that I should also mention this: My controller is partially working with Monogame. It does register input from my controller, but it is returning me values that are wrong. Also, my right stick does not work

Comment: Changing the gamepad deadzone to independent axes has made my left stick more accurate, but Monogame seems to only register Y inputs from my joystick, and it shouldn't be because the Y only changes when I move the stick left to right, not Up to down. The X doesn't change at all